# Travel to USA from another country and return to home country on a Business Visa B1

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, work, denmark

I am from India and have received my work permit for Denmark. I will soon travel to Denmark to work with the Danish company. However, within two-three weeks I need to visit the USA for attending some business meetings and then I will be traveling back to India for some time.

```
i.e.

India-->Denmark;

Denmark --> USA;

USA --> India
```

I have a work permit for Denmark and valid Business visa (B1) for the USA. Will this be ok or I will face any issues?

Answer (score 6):

There will be no problem. US visas, like most visas, are not conditional on your itinerary. The visa remains valid regardless of where you travel from.